# scrapy is not taking calculated list as start url but working fine with text url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape multiple urls and getting the following error on passing the start urls as calculated url( see the code). 
 **Error-**

***Crawling could not start: 'start_urls' not found or empty (but found
'start_url' attribute instead, did you miss an 's'?)*** 
 But everything is working fine on passing the string in list for start_ulr(see the commented part of code).
 Not able to figure out what wrong i am doing.
Any help would be appreciated.  
 **Code sample-**

```
class CompaniesSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'companies_s'
    allowed_domains = ['www.screener.in']
    df = pd.read_csv('Equity.csv')
    comp = df['url'].tolist()  #list of companies
    comp1 = [str(x) for x in comp]
    start_url = ["https://www.screener.in/company/" + e + "/consolidated/" for e in comp1]
    
    #start_urls = ['https://www.screener.in/company/AVANTIFEED/consolidated/','https://www.screener.in/company/GPIL/consolidated/','https://www.screener.in/company/ACRYSIL/consolidated/']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//h1[@class='margin-0']/text()").get()
        marketcap = response.xpath("//span/child::span/text()").get()

        yield{
                'name':title,
                'marketcap':marketcap}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Crawling could not start: 'start_urls' not found or empty (but found 'start_url' attribute instead, did you miss an 's'?)

You wrote `start_url` instead of `start_urls`.